# Creating objects from ModelResources in Django Tastypie

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, tastypie

I am unable to grasp the connection between the TastyPie `ModelResource` and the Django `Model`. I have looked at the cookbook and not been able to understand this.

I have a `NotificationData` class where each instance belongs to a Django user (using a ForeignKey). 
I want only authenticated Users to CRUD `NotificationData` objects, and this will be done from a native app. I'm using oauth2 for authentication, so you can assume that each request will be sent using an authentication header with access token.

How do I create a `NotificationData` object for the authenticated User using the `NotificationDataResource`? And how would I get the list of the `NotificationData` objects for that user?

#### models.py:

```
class NotificationData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)   
    notification = models.OneToOneField(Notification)
    shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

#### api.py:

```
class NotificationDataResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = NotificationData.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'notification_data'
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        authentication = OAuth20Authentication()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the 'getting started' document?

It explains what you're asking; you just need to set up the URL handlers

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html